# Apply Multiple filter in redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to apply multiple filter in redux action

on the basis of four fields name, entity, status, value

```
case SEARCH_ALERTS: return {
            ...state,
            alertList: state.alertList.filter(item => item.name!== action.payload)
        }
```

how to apply multiple filters at once to update alertList

Comment: users = users.filter(obj => obj.name == filter.name && obj.address == filter.address) like this i have tried but i am not sure if i am getting all the four values or just few of them

Answer (score 0):

You can just add conditions in the filter function return value

Example

```
case SEARCH_ALERTS: return {
        ...state,
        alertList: state.alertList.filter(item => item.name!== action.payload  && item.prop1 === action.prop1 && item.prop2 === action.prop2)
    }
```